# Using mysql with express/Node: Is using globals ok?

Tags: node.js, activerecord, express

I can easily enough attach a new connection within my express config to the database using:

```
global.db = new DB.adapter({});
```

Thereby I an access it throughout any models I may wish to create. (I am using [active record](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql-activerecord) and mysql with express).

However, is this in any way a) insecure, b) bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this would be insecure, but using globals in general is bad practice:

1. Includes DB global for modules that don't need it.  Doesn't matter too much, but is a bit unclean.
2. Tightly couples a specific DB instance with modules that *do* need it.

   - Makes testing more difficult
   - Makes it harder to change to a different DB for particular modules.

Instead it's much easier to just use CommonJS which is built into node and is very easy to use.

```
// db.js
module.exports = new DB.adapter({});

//index.js
var db = require("./db");
```

Answer (score 2):

Both.

**Insecure**: Any module can change the global context. As any other package repository out there, evil programmers may exist in NPM.

**Bad practice**: Some test frameworks even consider this as a error (Mocha, for example, but that's configurable). You're in a CommonJS environment, so use modules! Doing so your connection object cannot be lost when `require()`ing that module, the far I know.